# ScrollMagic not working with jQuery linked at bottom of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic

Is there a way to use ScrollMagic when jQuery is loaded from the bottom of the page? It works if I put jQuery in the  but not if I don't. So far the site has been working well with all the scripts loading at the bottom and I don't want to change that, just for ScrollMagic.

Moving inline SM scripts into linked .js files doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the bottom, first load jquery and then ScrollMagic.
here is a ScrollMagic wiki [link](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/wiki/Getting-Started-:-First-Steps#initial-setup) that might help.

Did you try the new [ScrollMagic 2.0](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic/tree/development#scrollmagic-v200-beta-)? there is no jquery dependency anymore, as well as gsap.